# how can i move div in a horizontal line?

Tags: css, html

I would like to know how can i move 3 div's into a horizontal line? 
  This is my code :

```
<div id="div1">
    <img id="poza1" src="http://s13.postimg.org/x0yjq2xxv/programare.jpg?noCache=13    97486136" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <img src="http://s11.postimg.org/axam9glov/administrare.jpg?noCache=1397486260" width="468" height="167" id="poza2" />
</div>
<div id="div3">
    <img id="poza3" src="http://s30.postimg.org/ly7cy5xrx/tacografe.jpg?noCache=1397486471" />
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `div { display : inline-block; }`

Comment: you could set the width and float left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
    float: left;
}
```

This works provided that the total width of all 3 DIVs is less than their parent (or the page)

Answer (score 4):

Add following class to all 3 divs

```
.divs
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS floating:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
   float: left;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like Parag Tyagi said. I would only add a little bit of compatibility for IE 7 and 8:

```
.div1, div2, div3 {
    display: inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;
    /*optionally*/
    max-width:33.33%;
}
```

Don't ever use floats to position your elements (unless they should be actually floated) as you will run into many funky issues with alignment and such.

Comment: `Don't ever use floats to position your elements (unless they should be actually floated)` - TRUE

Comment: @ParagTyagi well... I guess this is according to preferences, I am very fond of floats and I think they are much better in most situations especialy when it comes to designing responsive websites where `display:inline-block;` always leads to "funky issues" (refering to whitespace).

Comment: I beg your pardon web-tiki but this is only because you got accustomed to achieve this the wrong way and now are spreading the word. The float property is simply not meant to achieve this goal. See here: http://digital-photography.pl/scripts/how-to-properly-align-html-elements-with-css/

Comment: There is no "wrong way", there are solutions according situations. Both solutions can fit according to the situation and we don't know the OP's situation so he will have to choose. I just think you can't say "don't ever use floats to position your elements" because they can become very handy according to situation.